# Umbraco unpublish Event not working for the current node

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, umbraco, umbraco7

I am developing Umbraco 7 MVC application and my requirement is to add **Item** inside Umbraco. **Item name should be unique**. For that used the below code but  I am getting the error **"Oops: this document is published but is not in the cache (internal error)"**

```
      protected override void ApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication,
            ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            ContentService.Publishing += ContentService_Publishing;
        }


        private void ContentService_Publishing(IPublishingStrategy sender, PublishEventArgs<IContent> e)
        {
            try
            {
               if(newsItemExists)
               {
                  e.Cancel = true;
               }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                Logger.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Then I tried adding code to unpublish but its not working i.e the node is getting published. Below is my code

```
private void ContentService_Publishing(IPublishingStrategy sender, PublishEventArgs<IContent> e)
        {
            try
            {
               int itemId=1234; //CurrentPublishedNodeId
               if(newsItemExists)
               {
                  IContent content = ContentService.GetById(itemId);
                  ContentService.UnPublish(content);
                  library.UpdateDocumentCache(item.Id);
               }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                Logger.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

But with the above code, if you give the CurrentPublishedNodeId=2345 //someOthernodeId its unpublished correctly.

Can you please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do this, Umbraco will automatically append `(1)` to the name if the item already exists (so it IS unique).

If you don't want this behavior you can check in the following way:

```
protected override void ApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
    ContentService.Publishing += ContentService_Publishing;
}

private void ContentService_Publishing(Umbraco.Core.Publishing.IPublishingStrategy sender, PublishEventArgs<IContent> e)
{
    var contentService = UmbracoContext.Current.Application.Services.ContentService;

    // It's posible to batch publish items, so go through all items 
    // even though there might only be one in the list of PublishedEntities
    foreach (var item in e.PublishedEntities)
    {
        var currentPage = contentService.GetById(item.Id);

        // Go to the current page's parent and loop through all of it's children
        // That way you can determine if any page that is on the same level as the 
        // page you're trying to publish has the same name
        foreach (var contentItem in currentPage.Parent().Children())
        {
            if (string.Equals(contentItem.Name.Trim(), currentPage.Name.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I think your problem might be that you're not looping through all `PublishedEntities` but using some other way to determine the current page Id.

Note: Please please please do not use the `library.UpdateDocumentCache` this, there's absolutely no need, ContentService.UnPublish will take care of the cache state.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My client wants to show error message such as "The item exists." I am using PublishedEntities to get current Page Id and I will remove this "library.UpdateDocumentCache". In the line IContent content = ContentService.GetById(itemId); if I pass the currentpublilshedNodeId its not working but if I give some other node Id then its working.

Comment: Have you tried my code above? Don't use currentPublishedNodeId. You'll want to read up on custom messages over here as well: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-5927 - it's kinda possible now, but a bit hacky, it will be natively possible in 7.3.0.